# accessing object defined in constructor from within the same constructor

Tags: node.js, class, constructor

I have the following code:

```
module.exports = class TASKS {
  constructor() {
    this.tasks = {};
    let _previousStateHash = '';

    function save() {
      const newState = JSON.stringify(this.tasks);
      const newStateHash = hash(newState);
      if (newStateHash !== _previousStateHash) {
        fs.writeFileSync('./.persistance.json', newState);
        _previousStateHash = newStateHash;
      }
    }

   async function stateInit() {
      setInterval(() => {
        save();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

   // The rest of the class

}
```

I need to access `this.tasks = {}` defined in the beginning of the constructor within the `save()`, but whenever I run the code, I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined
    at save (/home/yury.stanev/menlolab/runner/lib/tasks.js:48:44)
    at Timeout.setInterval [as _onTimeout] (/home/yury.stanev/menlolab/runner/lib/tasks.js:80:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

I suspect it's the issue with `this` binding in the constructor. If I try to access it from within class outside of constructor it works just fine. How do I access elements in constructor from within it?

Comment: I think you need to bind the function to the class

Comment: That seems to have fixed the issue.